# Blurring the background of headers while maintaining separation

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface

Working template of the site: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-currying-3me1t

my `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements in `Header.js` have the `background-color: #000000;` property set. When the particles pass through the area that the headers are in, they are completely obscured by this background color.

How do I make the background color of the headers transparent? I want to be able to see the particles passing through the region as to maintain context.

The intended effect looks like the image below although I am trying to maintain the area in between the two headers being blur free.

[image: example]

Comment: background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); Should do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass the header (assumming You only need the header to be transparent),

```css
opacity: .5;
/* Or, */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

You might need to add some shadows and so on stuff to give that thing a transparent feel.